# How did Luna 3's pivoting antennas and ribbon antennas work?

Tags: antenna, soviet-union, luna

[This comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/17301/how-was-it-possible-for-the-apollo-11-to-film-and-take-pictures-with-such-radiat/17303#comment85261_17303) below [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/17303/12102) to *How was it possible for the Apollo 11 to film and take pictures with such radiation?* links to the svengrahn.pp.se post [Luna 3 - the first view of the moon's far side](http://www.svengrahn.pp.se/trackind/luna3/Luna3story.html).

It shows the annotated image below of Luna-3. The image is a partial cut-away view, the lower half shows the external area and the upper half shows some of the internal components I believe.

The three rod antennas attached to the "bottom" are labeled "Pivoting antennas" and the two at the "top" are labeled "Ribbon antennas".

**Question:** How did Luna 3's pivoting antennas and ribbon antennas work? Why did some antennas need to pivot, and others need to be ribbons?

---

> One of the origins of Luna-3 was the work by Boris Raushenbakh on attitude control started in 1955  in the NII-1 rocket research institute of the Ministry of Aviation. This work was co-ordinated with Korolev's design bureau and had as its goal stabilised photo-reconnaissance satellites. Raushenbakh's group was contracted by the lunar project section Korolev's design bureau OKB-1 to design the attitude control for the E-2 variant of lunar exploration craft intended to image the Moon's hidden side. The manager of the lunar probe project at OKB-1 was Gleb Maksimov. An excellent account of these early Soviet lunar missions can be found in (4) and (14). A cutaway sketch of the space probe with a Soviet-era translation of Russian captions added is shown below.
>
> <sup>4</sup>Asif A. Siddiqi, "First to the Moon", Journal of the British Interplanetary Society, Vol.51, pp.231-238, 1998.
>
> <sup>14</sup>Timothy Varfolomeyev, Journal of the British Interplanetary Society, Vol.52, pp.157-160, 1999.

click for full size

[image: Luna-3 from svengrahn.pp.se]

Comment: companion question: [What did Luna 3's illuminator illuminate and why did it need a cover?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/38930/12102)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, restore the original image captions.
[image]

pivoting antennas - штыревые антенны - Whip antennas

ribbon antennas - ленточные антенны.

For what range of radio frequencies?

> Частота передачи была равна 103 МГц, а частота приема — 183,6 МГц. Запасная система телеметрии работала на частоте 39,986 МГц. Космическая станция была оснащена шестью всенаправленными антеннами, четыре из которых выступали из верхней части, и две — из нижней.
> The transmission frequency was 103 MHz, and the receiving frequency was 183.6 MHz. The spare telemetry system worked at a frequency of 39.986 MHz. The space station was equipped with six omnidirectional antennas, four of which protruded from the top and two from the bottom.

Whip antennas  - conventional whip antennas for VHF have a short length of about two meters.

But longer wavelengths require longer antennas. For 40 MHz - this is 7.5 meters. How to place such antennas on a rocket?

Ribbon antenna:

> Ленточная антенна, выполнена в виде намотанной на барабан стальной
> ленты и снабженная механизмом механизмом для формирования при
> развертывании антенны полой трубки. The tape antenna is made in the
> form of a steel tape wound around a drum and equipped with a mechanism
> for creating a hollow tube when the antenna is deployed.

Videos that demonstrate this invention:
Luna-1 at 8:42

Luna-9 at 7:48

Comment: This is excellent, thank you very much!